# Use dropdown selection to open a page with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just looking for approach. I have a dropdown list for example (index, edit, new ). After selecting any of these and submitting the form, I want to go to a particular page. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to read about *html* and using of *forms* in it.

Comment: what does this have to do with ruby OR rails?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
  @addresses = {
    :home => root_path,
    :new_test => new_test_path,
    :name => some_path
  }
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= select "link", "somewhere", @addresses %>
  <%= submit_tag "Go", :id => "go" %>
<% end %>
```

In your application.js:

```
  $("input[type='submit']#go").bind('click', function(event){
    window.location = $("select#link_somewhere").val();
    event.preventDefault();
  })
```

That is in case you use jQuery. If you use prototype it's a bit different.